# Getting the "empty controlled statement found" warning | MetaEditor

Tags: mql4, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4, low-latency, forex

How would I ensure that the following `if`, `else if` statement follows the following rule:

> ***"If** everything in **either** `/*Condition 1*/` or `/*Condition 2*/` is true,
> then
> carry on assessing **`/*Conditions 3 - 12*/`**"*

At present, I am getting the *`empty controlled statement found 313 38`*  compiler error/warning.

```html
if(shiftOneClose < shiftOneOpen){ /*Condition 1*/
   if((bearHammer / (shiftOneOpen - shiftOneLow) <= OoTMax))
   if((bearHammer / bullNail) <= OoTMax)
   if(bearHammer >= Transform(PCM,2)); /*Line 313*/

}

else if(shiftOneClose > shiftOneOpen){ /*Condition 2*/
   if((bullHammer / (shiftOneClose - shiftOneLow) <= OoTMax))
   if((bullHammer / bullNail) <= OoTMax)
   if(bullHammer >= Transform(PCM,2));

}

if.... /*Conditions 3 - 12*/
if....
if....
if....
if....
if....
if....
if....
if....
if....
{

  [execute trade]

}
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. I have "ticked" your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use general control structures followed by other programming languages like C++, JAVA.

In case you are unfamiliar:
`&&` this indicates `and`
`||` this means `or`

Example:

```
//--- so in order to make it evaluate conditions 3-12, if only condition 1 or 2 is true
if(condition1 || condition2){
  if(condition3 && condition4){ /* so on until 12 */
     //--- execute trade
  }
}
```

**In order to improve the readability of the code I suggest you move some of the conditions into functions**

Comment: Why do you claim, a code-block constructor  if( C1 or C2 ){ if( C3 and ... and C12 ) { do_a_job; }  } is smarter, than a free-to-all compiler-based optimisation ***purely logic based*** constructor if( ( C1 or C2 ) and C3 and ... and C12 ){ do_a_job; }? If you find a reason to complicate a pure boolean logic composition, what evidence did drive you to propose steps that will produce a worse-performing code (that will avoid compiler-based optimisation to take place at runtime plus will add other add-on overheads that make the actual code-execution slower)? In FX domain ultra-low latency wins...

Comment: what are you referring to exactly? I never said anything is better than anything.
At the bottom what I said was, it would be much easier to read and understand if you move some of the logic to a function other than chaining each condition through `&& ||`.

Comment: Chained 2-ary if-s? if( A|B ){ if( C&D ){ if( E&F ){ if( G&H ){ if( I&J ){ if( K&L ){ ?; }}}}}}} is, out of question more an anti-pattern, than an example, isn't it? + recommending to add to any part of XTO-critical code-section any non-essential, latency increasing overheads? Again an anti-pattern not to be ever taught, the less replicated in [tag:algorithmic-trading] and [tag:low-latency], be it? With all due respect, the "code readability" discipline can help in shared-efforts (volunteered) code-maintaining cooperatives, not in XTO-critical code sections, where ultra low latency matters.OK?

Comment: I see, okay, 
Thanks for the valuable information.
Although I did not see the `low-latency` tag before. However, I only suggested an approach to the code shown by the OP.
However, I am curious to do you have MQL4 benchmarks that can prove one is better than the other?

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *"How would I ensure that the following `if`,`else if` statement follows the following rule:
>
> "If everything in either `/*Condition 1*/` or `/*Condition 2*/` is true,
> then carry on assessing `/*Conditions 3 - 12*/`""*

The original code blew up in *`line 313`*, because the **`;`**-character terminates a statement-constructor, while there was nothing to "execute" if (either) of the `if(){...}else{...}`-ed conditions were met (the same problem is in the `else{...}` part, where is also none `{...}`-code-block present and the formal-statement constructor gets panic not knowing what to "execute" in either of the `if(){...}else{...}`-branches, as the statement is formally not complete).

```
    if (  shiftOneClose < shiftOneOpen )                               /*Condition 1*/
    {                                                       
       if ( ( bearHammer / ( shiftOneOpen - shiftOneLow ) <= OoTMax )            )
       if ( ( bearHammer / bullNail )                     <= OoTMax              )
       if (   bearHammer                                  >= Transform( PCM, 2 ) ); /*Line 313*/

    }
```

So, not telling what to do if conditions get met is the root problem above.

---

### The Solution to the *"HOW WOULD I ENSURE ..."* part:

A syntactically correct would be this explanatory logic-preserving code template:

```
if (  (  (  shiftOneClose       <    shiftOneOpen
         && OoTMax              >= ( bearHammer / ( shiftOneOpen - shiftOneLow ) )
         && OoTMax              >= ( bearHammer / bullNail                       )
         && Transform( PCM, 2 ) <=   bearHammer
            ) /*--------------------------------------------------------------------- Condition 1 */
      || (  shiftOneClose       >    shiftOneOpen
         && OoTMax              >= ( bullHammer / ( shiftOneClose - shiftOneLow ) )
         && OoTMax              >= ( bullHammer / bullNail                        )
         && Transform( PCM, 2 ) <=   bullHammer
            ) /*---------------------------------------------------------------- .OR. Condition 2 */
         )
   && ( ... ) /*---------------------------------------------------------------- .AND.Condition 3 */
   && ( ... ) /*---------------------------------------------------------------- .AND.Condition 4 */
   && ( ... ) /*---------------------------------------------------------------- .AND.Condition 5 */
   && ( ... ) /*---------------------------------------------------------------- .AND.Condition 6 */
   && ( ... ) /*---------------------------------------------------------------- .AND.Condition 7 */
   && ( ... ) /*---------------------------------------------------------------- .AND.Condition 8 */
   && ( ... ) /*---------------------------------------------------------------- .AND.Condition 9 */
   && ( ... ) /*---------------------------------------------------------------- .AND.Condition A */
   && ( ... ) /*---------------------------------------------------------------- .AND.Condition B */
      )
   {...} /*---------------------------------- CODE-BLOCK TO EXECUTE ------------------------------*/
```

In my ~ 20+ years of Quant modelling, we always preferred to have wide-layout (screens are cheap and having 4 x 2 and larger multi-screen seats is so easy and so common in more than a recent decade ), emphasis on the logic, then reducing dup-es in computation(s) (best pre-computing any & all logic-"control-values" to be then re-used and due to low-latency ( often ultra-low-latency ) reasons, we never resorted to spend any extra time on calling function ( overheads with context-switching & passing parameters there & results back ). Not all compilers (versions) did short-cutting the execution branches due to laws-of-logic, so care must be taken here ( most expensive functions being those that manipulate/query the `db.POOL`-storage with trades' data, having an awfully expensive costs of first having to do a `db.POOL`-pointer manipulation and then & only then (on success thereof & never otherwise) re-access the `db.POOL`-record's items of data ).

One should also notice that there is a logical blind-spot -- `shiftOneClose == shiftOneOpen`.